# Adding hook without changing source code

Tags: java, hook

Is it possible to add a hook to a meothd without changing the method? For example:

```
public class class1{ 
    public void method1(){}
}
public class class2{
    public void method2(){}
}
```

Now how can I execute method2() everytime when method1() is executed, without changing anything in class1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as AOP or [Aspect Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), and is implemented via bytecode manipulation.

[Spring includes facilities for AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html).

A detailed description of AOP would be too long for StackOverflow, and redundant since there are many good resources on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Decorator pattern' to extend functionality of class1. This approach requires change in code that calls class1